# How to know the condition at which a thread is "waiting" for?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-dump

I am debugging a live environment and I have taken some thread dumps. I see that lot of thread are "waiting on condition"; but how can I know what that condition is?

The below is the snippet of real thread dump stack:

```
"Uploader-pool-job-create-ca2d264a-51b3-4fa3-8113- 
f0f0aca47add-StreamThread-10-0_14" #140 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 
tid=0x00007f006002b800 nid=0x18b waiting on condition 
[0x00007f004d9e1000]
 java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000002c20d4320> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Other:**

```
"Uploader-pool-job-create-ca2d264a-51b3-4fa3-8113- 
f0f0aca47add-StreamThread-3-0_16" #138 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 
tid=0x00000000025da000 nid=0x189 waiting on condition 
[0x00007f004dbe3000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000002c20d6690> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In these threads it is saying "waiting on condition"; but I can't decipher what that condition is on which the thread is waiting on?

--> In general, are there any guidelines how to understand thread dumps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all there in the stack trace - `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is [awaiting](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java#l1093) on the [`available`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java#l863) condition:

```
private final Condition available;
. . .

     available.awaitNanos(delay);   // ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093
```

In other words, the thread in the pool is idle and waiting for more work.

In general, the stack trace shows exactly the Java file name and line number where the thread of execution is currently at (usually when a thread is waiting, the deepest few levels would be too low-level, so just continue up the chain to find the most meaningful level).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, helped to understand. Is there a way to be able to understand Thread dumps in some "easy" way (of course it comes with experience and interest); but for who aren't that well versed with the subject, any tips please?

Comment: It comes with experience. Stack traces that looks like the two in the question are idle threads and can be ignored (it's normal that a lot of threads are idle in a Java application). Focus on threads that mention *your* packages in the stack trace and on threads in "runnable" state.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like they are waiting to acquire a lock. The condition in this case would be: waiting for the timeout to finish to attempt to acquire the lock.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000002c20d4320> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
```